# Entity Framework mapping between ASP Identity user and other tables - change Id column

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I have a standard `Identity` user in my app...

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{...
```

...Which has `Id` as primary key.
**How can I change `Id` to UserId?**
I ask this because I have table that should be connected with `AspNetUsers` table.
And I did it like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{...
public virtual ICollection<JobApply> JobApplies { get; set; }
```

And `JobApply` code is:

```
public class JobApply
{...
public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

The result of this is this:
[image]

I want to make this better somehow.
I want to have `UserId` instead `Id` so columns in both table to be names UserId.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the name.  Id is defined at the very bottom of the extension system in `IUser<T>`, which all `IdentityUser` implementations must ultimately inherit from.

Just no way to do it without rewriting everything.

You COULD change the name of the field as it's stored in the database, but you can't change the name of the property as used in code.  If you only want to change the name of the column in the database, then you need only use FluentConfiguration to change the name of the property.

EDIT:

In your ApplicationContext you would do this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .Property(p => p.Id)
        .HasColumnName("UserId");
}
```

Comment: You want to say that there is no way after generating database tables table `JobApply` have column `UserId` and it has to be `ApplicationUserId`? Off course without rewriting everyhing :)

Comment: `then you need only use FluentConfiguration to change the name of the property` can you give me short example how to make this, please?

Comment: @1110 - You weren't asking for JobApply to be UserId, you were asking for IdentityUser to have a different name for the Id.

Comment: Another question rise from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475351/asp-identity-table-column-change-but-mapping-is-not-possible-with-new-column-nam

Comment: i have similar scenario but i want the userid value be entered in id when creating a user on [Register] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663471/add-primary-key-of-linked-table-to-aspnetusers-table-id-field can someone help please..