# ASP Identity table column change but mapping is not possible with new column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I have changed the asp Identity so that in database `Id` column of `AspNetIdentity` table be `UserId`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                        .Property(p => p.Id)
                        .HasColumnName("UserId");
```

And that works fine. Generated table have `UserId` instead `Id`.
Now I have another table that should be mapped with `AspNetUsers` by `UserId`:
When write it this way:

```
public class JobApply
    {   ...
        public int UserId { get; set; }       
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

Table in database looks like:
[image]
And if I write it like this:

```
public class JobApply
    {   ...
        public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

database looks like:
[image]

First option created `UserId` field but it is not `FK` instead of that new field is added as `FK`.
How can I properly map this to have table `JobApply` with field `UserId` to be `FK` to `AspNetUsers`?

**UPDATE**

When I add this:

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                        .Property(p => p.Id)
                        .HasColumnName("UserId");

            modelBuilder.Entity<JobApply>()
                    .HasRequired(e => e.ApplicationUser)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);
```

Tables relation looks like this:
[image]
This is both classes:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
        public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
        public string PasswordResetToken { get; set; }

        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public virtual City City { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<JobApply> JobApplies { get; set; }
    }

public class JobApply
    {
        public int JobApplyId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        public int JobApplyStatusId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
        public virtual JobApplyStatus JobApplyStatus { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your relationship with the fluent API like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<JobApply>()
                    .HasRequired(e => e.ApplicationUser)
                    .WithMany(e => e.JobApplies)
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);
```

You may as well remove the property `UserId` from the `ApplicationUser` class and then define the mapping like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<JobApply>()
                    .HasRequired(e => e.ApplicationUser)
                    .WithMany(e => e.JobApplies)
                    .Map(m => m.MapKey("UserId"));
```

Comment: With this `UserId` becomes FK but field `ApplicationUser_Id` is also in the table?

Comment: No, if you define it like that ApplicationUser_Id won't be added any more as it won't be needed. ApplicationUser_Id is default name for ef for foreign key property to ApplicationUser class. If you specify this name yourself then it will override this default name.

Comment: But, if I remove `public virtual ICollection<JobApply> JobApplies { get; set; }` from `ApplicationUser` than I get only `UserId`. Now I am still new in EF but shouldn't I have this in my User class. If I need to get `context.Users.JobApplies.ToList();` if I remove that I can't do this.

Comment: I didn't know you have JobApplies property. I've editted my answer, could you check it?

Comment: Works perfect. Whole thing would be much easier if they make `Id` from `ApplicationUser` to be named `UserId` :) Tnx

Comment: @1110 - why would they want to do that?  Entity Framework's conventions are that it looks for primary keys to be named Id or ClassNameId (ie ApplicationUserId).  The whole thing here is just because you don't like the name Id and want it to be something else.  That's just user preference.

Comment: You are right it's user preference. I was just kidding about what ms should name it :-) I simply like UseId. What would you name columns in my situation (pk & fk)?