# Add Primary Key of Linked Table to ASPNETUsers table Id field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I have successfully linked aspnetusers table to my custom users table as one-to-one relationship. Now when i go to register all information is successfully added to both tables except one thing - Id.

My pk userId in users table is an AutoIncrement key and i wish to add the same value in the id field of aspnetUsers table. I think i will have to override createAsync or do i remove from SignInAsync

```
await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager)
```

Inside **AccountController** Register method, I have

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var geUser  = new User { Password = model.Password, Username = model.Email, AccessLevel = "0003", LoggedIn = false, Active = true, AllowOffline = false, LastSettingsRefreshed = DateTime.Now };

            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email,  user = geUser};
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

**My Data Tables:**
ASPNetUSers and Users respectively:

[image]

I want to enter 43 instead of 0 in aspnetusers table

**UPDATE**

On research i see that it has something to do with **DatabaseGeneratedOption** but exactly what and on which table should i do "DatabaseGeneratedOption.None"?

Comment: Since you do not have the data in ASPNetUSers table it will always start from 0.

Comment: this is what i want to change in implementation

Comment: I guess you cannot do it, for one to one relationship you have to start both the tables together then they will have the same ids or use the foreign key references.

Comment: I have already defined a one-to-one relationship in my dbcontext for refrence (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617017/how-to-link-one-to-one-relationship-when-fk-is-different-from-pk-entityframewo) how do i tell entity framework that take this key as id when inserting a record